# Add an item to an ICollection inside of a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I add one item to a collection inside if a select linq query?

```
IEnumerable<User> users
    = model.Select(u => new User
       {
            Username = u.Username,
            EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress,
            Federations = u.FederatedUsername != null ? new List<Federation>().Add(new Federation { FederatedUsername = u.FederatedUsername }) : null,
       });
```

However, I get an error void and null types are incompatible.

I have two entities with (pertinent) properties show below:

```
User
-----
UserID [PK]
Username
EmailAddress
...

Federation
----------
FederationID [PK]
UserID [FK]
FederatedUsername
```

However, I get an error Void and null types are incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> users =
    model
        .Select(u => new User
        {
                Username = u.Username,
                EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress,
                Federations =
                    u.FederatedUsername == null
                    ? new List<Federation>() :
                    (new []
                        {
                            new Federation()
                            {
                                FederatedUsername = u.FederatedUsername
                            },
                        }).ToList(),
        });
```

Comment: `(new [] { new Federation() { FederatedUsername = u.FederatedUsername } , } ).ToList()`? Why don't just `new List<Federation>() { new Federation { (..) } }`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Yes, that's good too. I just tend to use the array initializer as my main way to create an enumerable.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Oh, an I use this syntax when working with anonymous types. You can't do that when you declare the list up-front.

Answer (score 2):

```
new List<Federation>().Add(new Federation { FederatedUsername = u.FederatedUsername })
```

this piece of code does not return the list, because `Add` does not return anything.

Use collection initialization syntax instead:

```
new List<Federation>() { new Federation { FederatedUsername = u.FederatedUsername } }
```

so it should be:

```
Federations = u.FederatedUsername != null
                  ? new List<Federation>() {
                        new Federation {
                            FederatedUsername = u.FederatedUsername
                        }
                     }
                  : null,
```